# WinRT XAML Menu Navigation MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, navigation, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows 8.1 app, and I am trying to add a dynamically generated menu to the left side. I retrieve a list of MenuItem (defined below) and I would like to make a page that has a menu on the left side, and when you click on the MenuItem, it needs to navigate the other view/flipview/frame to the page associated with the menu item. I am using MVVM Light and have set up my navigation service, but it only navigates the main frame, and I only want a child view on the page to change.

For example, when you click on a menu item on the left, I want the the "DestinationPage" to show up on the right. I need this to be associated with a List or collection because each user will have a different list of MenuItem.

Additionally, I know this can be done through code-behind, but I want to stick to MVVM and have the ViewModel handle which page belongs in that child view. Thanks.

```
public class MenuItem : IMenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type DestinationPage { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class CustomerDetailsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _detailPageSource;
    private MenuItem _selectedMenuItem;


    public MenuItem SelectedMenuItem
    {
        get { return _selectedMenuItem; }
        set { Set(() => SelectedMenuItem, ref _selectedMenuItem, value); }
    }

    public RelayCommand<MenuItem> MenuItemSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<IMenuItem> Details { get; set; }

    public CustomerDetailsViewModel()
    {

        MenuItemSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand<MenuItem>(m => DetailPageSource = m.DestinationPageLocation);

        Details = new ObservableCollection<IMenuItem>()
        {
             new MenuItem()
            {   
                DestinationPage = typeof (Demographics),
                Name = "Demographics"
            },
            new MenuItem()
            {
                DestinationPage = typeof(OrderProductList),
                Name = "Test Another Type"
            }
        };

        SelectedMenuItem = Details.Single(m => m.Name == "Demographics") as MenuItem;
    }
```

[image: Example where gray area is navigation and blue area is separate view]

Example where gray area one view for navigation and blue area is separate view for content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by doing the following:

1. Adding a FlipView control to the page
2. Binding the FlipView to the MenuItem collection
3. Creating a MenuItemDataTemplateSelector

My code is as follows:

Xaml:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="LightGray">
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Customer Details</TextBlock>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>

        <FlipView Grid.Column="1" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MenuNameDataTemplateSelector}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Details, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <FlipView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Demographics">
                    <details:Demographics />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Order History"></DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Communication Settings"></DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Alerts"></DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Order Product List">
                    <views:OrderProductList />
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.Resources>
        </FlipView>


    </Grid>
```

MenuItemDataTemplateSelector

```
public class MenuNameDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var menuItem = item as MenuItem;
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (menuItem != null || element != null)
        {
            while (element != null)
            {
                while (element != null)
                {
                    if (element.Resources.ContainsKey(menuItem.Name))
                    {
                        var template = element.Resources[menuItem.Name] as DataTemplate;
                        if (template != null)
                            return template;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as FrameworkElement;

                        if (element == null)
                            element = element.Parent as FrameworkElement;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
    }
}
```

and View Model

```
public class CustomerDetailsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _detailPageSource;
    private MenuItem _selectedMenuItem;


    public MenuItem SelectedMenuItem
    {
        get { return _selectedMenuItem; }
        set { Set(() => SelectedMenuItem, ref _selectedMenuItem, value); }
    }

    public RelayCommand<MenuItem> MenuItemSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<IMenuItem> Details { get; set; }

    public CustomerDetailsViewModel()
    {

       Details = new ObservableCollection<IMenuItem>()
        {
             new MenuItem()
            {   
                DestinationPage = typeof (Demographics),
                Name = "Demographics"
            },
            new MenuItem()
            {
                DestinationPage = typeof(OrderProductList),
                Name = "Order Product List"
            }
        };

        SelectedMenuItem = Details.Single(m => m.Name == "Demographics") as MenuItem;
    }

    public override void ClearViewModel()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```